# jQuery.ajax call to reset password doesn't work in IE8 but works fine in other browsers

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In Visualforce page I have an ajax call to reset user password's

```
$j.ajax({
   crossDomain:true,
   url:"https://test.salesforce.com/secur/forgotpassword.jsp?un=user@myOrg.com",
   type:"GET"
});
```

If I test this in Chrome or Firefox, when I click on the submit button, I receive the e-mail from salesforce but not in IE7/8

Any ideas why and for a workaround ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $j('<img src="https://test.salesforce.com/secur/forgotpassword.jsp?un=user@myOrg.com" with=1 height=1 >').appendTo('body');
```

I think is a security limitation of IE, but if the method is GET you can use this trick.

Comment: Martin, where I can add this ? thanks

Comment: Replace the ajax call for this code. I suppose you have a link or button to call it.